# Lowercase each arguments of a function

Tags: php, function, arguments

I need to lowercase each arguments of my function.

```
function somefunc($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g) {
    $a = mb_strtolower($a);
    $b = mb_strtolower($b);
    $c = mb_strtolower($c);
    $d = mb_strtolower($d);
    $e = mb_strtolower($e);
    $f = mb_strtolower($f);
    $g = mb_strtolower($g);
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work properly:

```
function somefunc($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as $h) {
        $h=mb_strtolower($h);
    }
}
```

How should I do?

Comment: Do you want to modify by reference or return the updated variables as an array?

Comment: I want to modify the original arguments, so I'm not really sure but I think by reference.

Comment: Please forgive my persistence, but can you show how you are using these modified strings within the scope of the custom function?  I might want to offer further insights on best practice -- either to change the technique within the function or to move logic out of your function and into your global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify by reference (no return value) by adding `&` to each of the incoming parameters of your custom function.

`array_walk()` complained about iterating these references, so I settled for a classic `foreach()` loop (which also modifies by reference).

If you print them out... `func_get_args()` is less cooperative than `get_defined_vars()` because the former creates an indexed array and the latter creates an associative array which maintains the variable relationships.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8j6SZ))

```
function somefunc(&$a, &$b, &$c, &$d, &$e, &$f, &$g) {
    foreach (get_defined_vars() as &$v) {
        $v = mb_strtolower($v);
    }
}

$a = 'HÈllo1';
$b = 'HÈllo2';
$c = 'HÈllo3';
$d = 'HÈllo4';
$e = 'HÈllo5';
$f = 'HÈllo6';
$g = 'HÈllo6';

somefunc($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g);
var_export([$a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'hèllo1',
  1 => 'hèllo2',
  2 => 'hèllo3',
  3 => 'hèllo4',
  4 => 'hèllo5',
  5 => 'hèllo6',
  6 => 'hèllo6',
)
```

Comment: @Eglit I thought you told me that you didn't want to `return` the values as an array, but modify the variables by reference.  This is a major point of difference between the accepted answer and my answer.  The accepted answer does not modify the incoming variables, you would need to return the variables as an associative array and then `extract()` them or something.  My answer does not suffer such extra work.  May be you could tell us how you are using this custom function so that we can make better sense of it.

Comment: Sorry. I also told you I wasn't sure about it, because that concept (by reference) is new to me. The first accepted answer did the job well. But I admit your is working well also, meet all my needs and finally is the one with more detailled explanation.
I give you the accepted answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The other answer works just fine if you are only handling the variables within the scope of the custom function.  If you need to access these mutated strings in the global scope (after returning from the custom function), my answer provides that functionality, the other answer will not preserve the mutations.  I am not grubbing for the green tick, I care about the clarity of your requirements so that it is 100% clear if an answer is right, wrong, or just a misunderstanding.  This is me caring about Stackoverflow.

Comment: It appears I don't need those strings outside of this given function. Still, this concept of reference is useful to me, I appreciate you introduce it to me, and understand this is not mandatory for my case. I also value the fact you ask more explantion on some answers, so at the end of the day I let you the tick! Thank you for taking care about my requirements and Stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function somefunc($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g) {
    $args = array_map('mb_strtolower', func_get_args());
```

Comment: Where is the explanation with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use also next function:

```
function all_to_lower(...$args){

    foreach($args as &$arg){
        $arg = strtolower($arg);   // or mb_strtolower
    } 

    return $args;  
}

$out = all_to_lower('TRETE','QQREWR');

print_r($out);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/AYfq0)**

In your case you need to replace your foreach loop with:

```
foreach($args as &$arg) {
    $arg = mb_strtolower($arg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method, first get list of all arguments of a function, the iterate on them and change them.

```
function somefunc($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g) {
    $params = (new ReflectionFunction(__FUNCTION__))->getParameters();
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        ${$param->name} = mb_strtolower(${$param->name});
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** when you have a variable name in string, like `"a"` for example, you can use `${"a"}` to point at variable `$a`.

Comment: Where is the explanation with this answer?  Yikes, "variable variables"? No thanks.

Comment: @mickmackusa I just missed it. Then edited and added.

Answer (score -1):

```php
    function somefunc($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g) {
        // get all parameter value with key
        $args = get_defined_vars();
        // loop $args
        foreach($args as $key => $val) {
            // assign lowered $val to variable named from $key value
            ${$key} = mb_strtolower($val);
        }
    }
```

Demo : https://3v4l.org/EWGVg

Comment: Overengineering.